# Memory exhaustion with small files

Tags: php

Never come across this before...

I'm uploading 2 files, one that is 371kb and another than is 291kb.

```
public function useImage($image, $photoid){

    $source = $image['tmp_name'];
    $target = "projectimages/";

    //prepare the largest image

    $targetname = $photoid."large.jpg";
    $file = $target . $targetname;
    copy($source, $file);

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);

    $modwidth = 800;

    $diff = $width / $modwidth;

    $modheight = $height / $diff;
    $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height);

    imagejpeg($tn, $file, 100);

    //prepare the smaller image

    $targetname = $photoid."small.jpg";
    $file = $target.$targetname;
    move_uploaded_file($source, $file);

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);

    $modwidth = 400;

    $diff = $width / $modwidth;

    $modheight = $height / $diff;
    $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height);

    imagejpeg($tn, $file, 100);

}
```

I use this function to resize them to make them smaller, the function is ran for each image.

When reaching the smaller image section of the function, the photo isn't being resized and instead an error is popping up saying:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10368 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bs/classes/image.php on line 202
```

Which is on this line:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
```

How are these small images exhausting all the memory?

Thanks.

Comment: Filesize is a lot less important than horizontal and vertical resolution, and colour depth.... memory needed simply to hold the image data is horizontal x vertical x 4 (colour) bytes; so a 1024 x 768 pixel image needs at least 3,145,728 bytes (about 3MB)

Comment: Ok, so I have an allocated of 33mb roughly? 2600 x 2000 is the image, meaning it will require roughly 20mb. Because I copy the image and then move the original and they are both images of roughly 20mb, will that take me to 40mb and over the limit at it's being done in one function? Is that how it works?

Comment: basically, yes..... you have both $image and $tn in memory at the same time; that's 2600x2000x4 + 800x615x4 plus the working space for your imagejpeg() call, plus the memory for PHP itself, and for the code of your script, plus small amounts of memory for other variables. Working with images is always a very memory hungry process

Comment: Ok that's a great explanation, I 100% understand the problem now. I've never come across it before but I've always limited the size of images below this. Where are the breakpoints in memory then? Where you get a clean slate? Because when I submit the form that sets all this in motion, it's going to deal with 2 separate images, copy them both to make 4 and then do the resize etc. Will all that happen in one amount of memory?

Comment: The image data is only using local variables in the scope of the useImage() method, so memory for those variables is freed once that method call finishes; so as long as you have adequate memory for each pair of images, then it shouldn't be an issue... you can also free up memory manually after processing your large image by unsetting $tn and $image

Comment: So once the variables are out of scope, you get the memory back, so in this case, just within the function. That makes sense and also allows a way to break it down into separate functions to break the memory up throughout. Makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: That's right - you could simplify your code by having a function to handle a single file that was called twice from useImage, once for the large image, once for the smaller image; and memory would be freed up after each call

Comment: That is how I usually use this code, purely for code repetition purposes. I hadn't considered how the memory is allocated to not getting this problem before owes more to luck than chance! I've solved it now and learnt a fair bit about it all as a result. Thanks bud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't forget that those tiny .jpg images when uncompressed by the line you highlighted will become much larger in-memory bitmaps

eg: width in px * height in px * colour depth bits...

Comment: Ok, so I have an allocated of 33mb roughly? 2600 x 2000 is the image, meaning it will require roughly 20mb. Because I copy the image and then move the original and they are both images of roughly 20mb, will that take me to 40mb and over the limit at it's being done in one function? Is that how it works?

Comment: I think your on the right track.  To fix this you could try things like assigning null to any large objects you've finished with, limit the pixel size of images you accept, shell out and use something like imagemagick to do the resize or just bite the bullet and allow more memory in php.ini

Comment: Yeah completely on the right track now! I think the answer is to limit the pixel size of the uploaded image, considering I'm coming down to 800 from 2600, there's a lot of room for that. On my MAMP server, changing memory in php.ini won't be a problem but I imagine when this is on shared hosting, that becomes an issue! I'll research it but are there are major disadvantages to allocating more memory as you wrote 'bite the bullet'?

Comment: the disadvantage of allocating more memory is that you can potentially use a lot of memory ;-) as you mentioned this could well be impossible in a shared hosting environment.  It can also be undesirable in high traffic situations.  On the other hand, it could just do exactly what you want possibly combined with an image size check to give the user a message saying image too big instead of some memory error from php

Comment: Well on my MAMP server, 32mb is the limit but my shared hosting is 90mb so I need to change that to allow the extra which will comfortably do what I require. This can be changed in the php.ini?

Comment: Perfect, sorted! What's interesting is how you ensure a limit on users when if they exceed it, you get a php error!